# Seaborn - ScatterPlot with Average Y-axis

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I have written the below code in the seaborn scatterplot for the visual to create

`sns.scatterplot(x="Year_Birth", y="NumStorePurchases", data=md)`

I get the plot in the format below

[image]

I now need the average of the Y- axis and want to adjust the plot to look like the below picture

[image]

I have tried using the np.mean in the estimator but it has not worked out. Is there something that is being wrongly done? How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want one y-value for each x-value, you can create a `sns.pointplot(...,orient='v')`.  Note that a [pointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) uses a categorical axis, considering the x-values as strings, internally numbered `0,1,2,...`. By default, each of these x-values will be labeled. A `MultipleLocator` can be used to only show e.g. every 10.

To suppress lines joining all the values, use `join=False`, while `ci=None` suppresses the error lines of the confidence intervals.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

md = pd.DataFrame({"Year_Birth": np.random.randint(1940, 2000, 200),
                   "NumStorePurchases": np.random.randint(0, 14, 200)})
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.pointplot(x="Year_Birth", y="NumStorePurchases", order=range(1900, 2020),
                   orient='v', join=False, ci=None, color='cornflowerblue', data=md)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.pointplot]